# Server Error in python CGI

Tags: python, python-3.x, xampp, cgi

I am trying to implement cgi programming in python, for that i have Xampp server installed and configured on my system,I have updated the files as per the configuration required for the CGI programming but i still seem to have some error that results in the following on browser :

```
Server error!
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 500
localhost
Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.20
```

I have referred to many resources and have also reinstalled the tool multiple times but it does not seem to help.

Comment: Have you looked into the python Django webserver? It may be exactly what you're looking for, with most of the work already done for you.

Comment: What does Apache's `error.log` say?

Comment: Try the [`cgitb` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgitb.html)

Comment: have already tried cgitb module,

Comment: apache's error.log gives "[Tue Jun 19 08:34:34.679571 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1220:tid 268] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads."